# Cocoa app, create new instance of app with file new?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've created a mac application. Runs great, all is good. However, I want to be able to have multiple instance of the same app. So, all my app has is one window and a view controller. I would like to allow the user to go to File -> new and instantiate a new fresh instance of the already opened window, so the user can have as many open at the same time and have each handle its own options.

I hope this makes sense. I am new to Mac Development. I am not sure how to go about this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I want to be able to have multiple instance of the same app.

Don't. This is not an idiomatic behavior for macOS applications; there should only be one instance of an application open at a time.

If you want to allow the user to open multiple *windows* (like you can in TextEdit, for instance), what you are describing is typically known as a [document-based application](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Designing/Designing.html). Read Apple's documentation for details on how to create one, and what it will do for you.

Comment: I'll look into it and test it out. Thank you